# how to setup supervisor for django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-channels

I have a problem with my configurations from the supervisor, well this is happening.

my app is a server web socket when a run with de gunicorn like this

```
#>gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 colonybit.asgi:application
```

this command run perfectly, but web sockets not working, when I run with the command traditional from django like this:

```
#>python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0.0:8001
```

working well, but the server is down if don't an activity, and decide install supervisor, I run this command $ sudo supervisorctl reread, not working and send me this message error like this

```
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
```

I followed these tutorials

1: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

and this

2: https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor#configuration

the first tutorial uses it gunicorn, but I not use it
the second user django-supervisor but is discontinued

my configurations is:

root@ip-172-31-28-226:/etc/supervisor/conf.d#

realtimecolonybit.conf

```
    [program:realtimecolonybit]
      command = /home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/colonybit/manage.py 
      runserver host=0.0.0.0 port=8001 ; Command to start app
      user = root                                                         ; User to run as
      stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/logs/realtime.log   ; Where to write log messages
      redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
      environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8                       ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

please help me, how to config my server using python manage.py etc

I work with web sockets and use django-channels, python3.6, my machine is AWS in ubuntu LTS

thank for your attention.

regards
Ngel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is you are not defining the python path which you are using. Kindly setup a virtualenv for the python and then define it. Currently supervisord are using the default *python 2.7* installed

I have not used supervisord but I guess it would be similar to what systemd does.

Kindly follow the below guide and implement the changes as per supervisord or else you can use systemd too.

[Systemd setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Read the difference too between them

[Systemd vs Supervisord](https://gunes.io/2017/08/25/systemd-vs-supervisor/)